# Bringing a form window to the top of the application without being on top of all applications

Tags: c#, winforms, topmost

I have a modeless singleton form that appears on a timer.

If the application the form belongs to is the active application but the form is not on top, I want the form to be shown on top of all other windows of the application. It is up to the user if they then click away from it to push it behind other windows of the application.

If the application the form belongs to is not the active application, then I want the taskbar icon to flash (this is working), and I want the form to appear on top of all others only within that application, so when a user goes back to it, it is there for them to deal with.

I've tried using `form.BringToFront()` and `form.TopMost = true; form.TopMost = false;` but both of those solutions bring the form to the top of all applications. I don't want to annoy my users if they're working in another program.

Is there a way of achieving what I want?

Form activation function:

```
    public static RemindersList CreateInstance(List<Reminder> rs)
    {
        if (_singleton == null)
        {
            _singleton = new RemindersList(rs);
            _singleton.Activate();
            _singleton.TopMost = true;
            _singleton.TopMost = false;
            // Flash in taskbar if not active window
            FlashWindow.Flash(_singleton);
            return _singleton;
        }
        else
        {
            _singleton.TopMost = true;
            _singleton.TopMost = false;
            // Flash in taskbar if not active window
            FlashWindow.Flash(_singleton);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you create and launch the child form, do you specify the "owner" in the Show() method? I think that helps.

Comment: I just answered a question very similar to this earlier today. But it doesn't look like you're the same person who asked that one. The key is what Rennie already said: setting the *owner* of the modeless dialog to be your application's main form.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the NotifyIcon?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx